# Navigating the C-source code for names with underscores

Tags: help-mode

Is there a built-in option or a package that can help me navigate the C-source code to jump to functions, variables and other items with underscores in the name?

**Example # 1**:  I would like to place my cursor on `optional_new_start` in `window.c` -- hit an `M-x find-...` -- and be automatically transported to `window.h` at the location that tells me:

```
/* True means we have explicitly changed the value of start,
   but that the next redisplay is not obliged to use the new value.
   This is used in Fdelete_other_windows to force a call to
   Vwindow_scroll_functions; also by Frecenter with argument.  */
bool_bf optional_new_start : 1;
```

**Example # 2**:  I would like to place my cursor on `redisplay_window` -- hit an `M-x find-...` -- and be automatically transported to `xdisp.c` -- where I can read about:

```
static void
redisplay_window (Lisp_Object window, bool just_this_one_p)
{
  struct window *w = XWINDOW (window);
  struct frame *f = XFRAME (w->frame);
***
```

Comment: I don't work in C, but I came across this recently: http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html Check out the section on source code navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs can do this "out of the box". See [Tags](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html#Tags) in the manual. (Press `C-h r m tags RET` to read this section in Emacs.)

Here's what I did to make sure it works.

1. Got Emacs sources from https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs
2. Ran `find . -iname "*.c" -or -iname "*.h" | xargs etags` to create a TAGS table.
3. Added this `TAGS` table using `M-x visit-tags-table`.

Now I can put my cursor on `optional_new_start` in `window.c`, press `M-. RET` and end up on the appropriate line in `window.h`.

You can then press `M-*` to go back to the point you started from.

PS: It does not matter if variable and function names have underscores in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ggtags](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags), a frontend GNU Global.
It works pretty well and it is similar to the standard `etags` package.

From the **Usage** instructions:

> Open any file in a project and type `M-x ggtags-mode`. Use `M-.`
>   (`ggtags-find-tag-dwim`) to find the tag at point. If the project has
>   not been indexed (i.e. no `GTAGS` file exists), `ggtags` will ask for the
>   project root directory and index it recursively.

So, open `window.c`, then type `M-x ggtags-mode`.
Place the cursor on `optional_new_start` and hit `M-.`.
The first time you  will get a prompt (`ggtags-create-tags`) to create the `GTAGS` file needed.
(In fact, it will create four files: `GPATH`, `GTAGS`, `GRTAGS`, `GSYMS`.)

Hit `RET` and you will get a prompt like: `Use 'ctags' backend? (yes or no)`.
Type `yes` and you are done.

You can jump to definitions, find references, etc...